# Can I use the 'execute-api' service with the Javascript aws-sdk?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm calling an Amazon service that falls under the `execute-api` service, but I can't find in the [Javascript SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/) how to do that. It seems like I can only call specific services. So can I call something that fall unders `execute-api` with the SDK?